# css file can not be read?

Tags: deploy, magento-cloud, failed

I am trying to deploy a magento2.4.4 cloud staging environment and getting the below error. I am not sure how to troubleshoot this.

```
 The contents from the "/app/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/base/default/./node_modules/@spectrum-css/vars/dist/spectrum-global.css" file can't be read
```

Comment: I tried editing the config.php and disabling all adobestock modules but still when I then push that change I get the above error. anyone else ever experience this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento has published a patch for this for Magento **2.4.5**: "ACSD-46815: static content deploy fails when using compact strategy".

> The ACSD-46815 patch fixes the issue where the static content deployment fails when the compact strategy is used. This patch is available when the Quality Patches Tool (QPT) 1.1.20 is installed.

Read more about this patch at
https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-knowledge-base/kb/support-tools/patches/v1-1-20/acsd-46815-static-content-deploy-fails-when-using-compact-strategy.html

Possibly, you can also apply the patch via composer, here is the patch file content
https://github.com/magento/quality-patches/blob/master/patches/os/ACSD-46815_2.4.5_v2.patch

As for Magento **2.4.4**, I've written a patch for this issue:

```
diff --git a/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Collector/Collector.php b/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Collector/Collector.php
index b09001a7ac04..441d165f6792 100644
--- a/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Collector/Collector.php
+++ b/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Collector/Collector.php
@@ -93,6 +93,9 @@ public function collect()
                 if ($file->getModule() && !$this->moduleManager->isEnabled($file->getModule())) {
                     continue;
                 }
+                if (!$file->getFileName()) {
+                    continue;
+                }
                 $file->setDeployedFileName($this->fileNameResolver->resolve($file->getFileName()));
                 $params = $this->getParams($file);
                 $packagePath = "{$params['area']}/{$params['theme']}/{$params['locale']}";
diff --git a/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Package/Processor/PreProcessor/Css.php b/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Package/Processor/PreProcessor/Css.php
index 152c95f86552..6fc9c05eb352 100644
--- a/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Package/Processor/PreProcessor/Css.php
+++ b/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Package/Processor/PreProcessor/Css.php
@@ -120,6 +120,20 @@ private function hasOverrides(PackageFile $parentFile, Package $package)
         return false;
     }
 
+    /**
+     * See if given path is local or remote URL
+     *
+     * @param string $path
+     * @return bool
+     */
+    private function isLocal(string $path): bool
+    {
+        $pattern = '{^(file://(?!//)|/(?!/)|/?[a-z]:[\\\\/]|\.\.[\\\\/]|[a-z0-9_.-]+[\\\\/])}i';
+        $result = preg_match($pattern, $path);
+
+        return is_int($result) ? (bool) $result : true;
+    }
+
     /**
      * Build map file
      *
@@ -135,13 +149,22 @@ private function buildMap($packagePath, $filePath, $fullPath)
             $imports = [];
             $this->map[$fullPath] = [];
 
-            $content = $this->staticDir->readFile($this->minification->addMinifiedSign($fullPath));
+            $tmpFilename = $this->minification->addMinifiedSign($fullPath);
+            if ($this->staticDir->isReadable($tmpFilename)) {
+                $content = $this->staticDir->readFile($tmpFilename);
+            } else {
+                $content = '';
+            }
 
             $callback = function ($matchContent) use ($packagePath, $filePath, &$imports) {
-                $importRelPath = $this->normalize(pathinfo($filePath, PATHINFO_DIRNAME) . '/' . $matchContent['path']);
-                $imports[$importRelPath] = $this->normalize(
-                    $packagePath . '/' . pathinfo($filePath, PATHINFO_DIRNAME) . '/' . $matchContent['path']
-                );
+                if ($this->isLocal($matchContent['path'])) {
+                    $importRelPath = $this->normalize(
+                        pathinfo($filePath, PATHINFO_DIRNAME) . '/' . $matchContent['path']
+                    );
+                    $imports[$importRelPath] = $this->normalize(
+                        $packagePath . '/' . pathinfo($filePath, PATHINFO_DIRNAME) . '/' . $matchContent['path']
+                    );
+                }
             };
             preg_replace_callback(Import::REPLACE_PATTERN, $callback, $content);
 
diff --git a/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Package/Processor/PreProcessor/Less.php b/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Package/Processor/PreProcessor/Less.php
index dbda66cc948f..f4339b40f5be 100644
--- a/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Package/Processor/PreProcessor/Less.php
+++ b/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Package/Processor/PreProcessor/Less.php
@@ -3,6 +3,7 @@
  * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
  * See COPYING.txt for license details.
  */
+
 namespace Magento\Deploy\Package\Processor\PreProcessor;
 
 use Magento\Deploy\Console\DeployStaticOptions;
@@ -10,10 +11,10 @@ use Magento\Deploy\Package\Package;
 use Magento\Deploy\Package\PackageFile;
 use Magento\Deploy\Package\Processor\ProcessorInterface;
 use Magento\Deploy\Service\DeployStaticFile;
-use Magento\Framework\View\Asset\PreProcessor\FileNameResolver;
-use Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Minification;
 use Magento\Framework\Css\PreProcessor\Instruction\Import;
+use Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Minification;
 use Magento\Framework\View\Asset\NotationResolver;
+use Magento\Framework\View\Asset\PreProcessor\FileNameResolver;
 use Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Repository;
 
 /**
@@ -58,6 +59,11 @@ class Less implements ProcessorInterface
      */
     private $map = [];
 
+    /**
+     * @var array
+     */
+    private $pFileCache = [];
+
     /**
      * Less constructor
      *
@@ -67,10 +73,10 @@ class Less implements ProcessorInterface
      * @param Minification $minification
      */
     public function __construct(
-        FileNameResolver $fileNameResolver,
+        FileNameResolver        $fileNameResolver,
         NotationResolver\Module $notationResolver,
-        DeployStaticFile $deployStaticFile,
-        Minification $minification
+        DeployStaticFile        $deployStaticFile,
+        Minification            $minification
     ) {
         $this->fileNameResolver = $fileNameResolver;
         $this->notationResolver = $notationResolver;
@@ -94,7 +100,7 @@ class Less implements ProcessorInterface
                 if ($packageFile && $packageFile->getOrigPackage() === $package) {
                     continue;
                 }
-                $deployFileName = $this->fileNameResolver->resolve($file->getFileName());
+                $deployFileName = $this->fileNameResolver->resolve($file->getFileName() ?? '');
                 if ($deployFileName !== $file->getFileName()) {
                     if ($this->hasOverrides($file, $package)) {
                         $file = clone $file;
@@ -131,6 +137,7 @@ class Less implements ProcessorInterface
         $currentPackageFiles = array_merge($package->getFilesByType('less'), $package->getFilesByType('css'));
 
         foreach ($currentPackageFiles as $file) {
+            $this->pFileCache = [];
             if ($this->inParentFiles($file->getDeployedFileName(), $parentFile->getFileName(), $map)) {
                 return true;
             }
@@ -139,8 +146,10 @@ class Less implements ProcessorInterface
     }
 
     /**
-     * @param string  $fileName
-     * @param string  $parentFile
+     * Checks if there is a LESS file in current package which used for generating given CSS from parent package
+     *
+     * @param string $fileName
+     * @param string $parentFile
      * @param array $map
      * @return bool
      */
@@ -151,7 +160,13 @@ class Less implements ProcessorInterface
                 return true;
             } else {
                 foreach ($map[$parentFile] as $pFile) {
-                    return $this->inParentFiles($fileName, $pFile, $map);
+                    if (in_array($pFile, $this->pFileCache)) {
+                        continue;
+                    }
+                    $this->pFileCache[] = $pFile;
+                    if ($this->inParentFiles($fileName, $pFile, $map)) {
+                        return true;
+                    }
                 }
             }
         }
@@ -170,13 +185,15 @@ class Less implements ProcessorInterface
     {
         $content = $this->deployStaticFile->readTmpFile($filePath, $packagePath);
         $replaceCallback = function ($matchedContent) use ($filePath, $packagePath, $contentType) {
-            $matchedFileId = $matchedContent['path'];
+            $matchedFileId = $matchedContent['path'] ?? '';
+            // phpcs:ignore Magento2.Functions.DiscouragedFunction
             if (!pathinfo($matchedContent['path'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION)) {
                 $matchedFileId .= '.' . $contentType;
             }
             if (strpos($matchedFileId, Repository::FILE_ID_SEPARATOR) !== false) {
                 $basePath = $packagePath;
             } else {
+                // phpcs:ignore Magento2.Functions.DiscouragedFunction
                 $basePath = pathinfo($filePath, PATHINFO_DIRNAME);
             }
             $resolvedPath = str_replace(Repository::FILE_ID_SEPARATOR, '/', $matchedFileId);
@@ -205,7 +222,7 @@ class Less implements ProcessorInterface
      */
     private function normalizePath($path)
     {
-        if (strpos($path, '/../') === false) {
+        if ($path === null || strpos($path, '/../') === false) {
             return $path;
         }
         $pathParts = explode('/', $path);
```

Comment: Thank's I did see the patch but it does not work with 2.4.4

Comment: @Jayreis Yeah, I can see one of the files in that patch has been changed in 2.4.5. Could you add the file content of the file below in your 2.4.4 to somewhere like https://pastecode.io/ ? I'll create a patch for you. vendor/magento/module-deploy/Package/Processor/PreProcessor/Less.php

Comment: Alright, I'll add the patch for 2.4.4 in a few hours.

Comment: @Jayreis I've added the patch for Magento 2.4.4, please give it a try.

Comment: Thank you Tu Van. Should I copy your 2.4.4 patch code and put it in the hotfixes folder and then push it up? what should I name the file? thanks

Comment: Yep, I think the same. You should name the patch file to describe what is it for, eg: ACSD-46815_2.4.4-fix-static-deployment-fails.patch and put it in the `m2-hotfixes` folder and then push it up. Here is the document to apply a composer patch on cloud https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-knowledge-base/kb/how-to/how-to-apply-a-composer-patch-provided-by-magento.html
and https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-cloud-service/user-guide/develop/upgrade/apply-patches.html#:~:text=Copy-,Apply%20a%20custom%20patch,-When%20you%20deploy

Comment: Thank you Tu Van. I will have to contact Adobe Support which I already have a ticket open with because I did the above adding the file to m2-hotfixes and pushing it up and got an error saying Error: Environment creation failed
       Please contact support for more information,
       specifying event ids: 0377356b3cef4609967fe1e7aea8fcc4, 055a052c035b4fb69cd571fc83344d2a

Comment: Yeah, please keep me posted.

Comment: I will keep you posted

Answer (score 0):

I often had issue with file permission. Did you check? [Magento docs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/prod/prod_file-sys-perms.html)